# ASP.NET Identity - Different MaxFailedAccessAttempts for different users

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity

How can I configure MaxFailedAccessAttempts dynamically so that it is user specific? The user specific attempts are stored in cache and should apply when they try to log in.

This is how I am currently setting the MaxFailedAccessAttempts

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, Role>(config =>
        {
            config.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 3;
            config.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(24);
        })
```

However, I have different MaxFailedAccessAttempts values for different users. For instance, a manager user might have 3 max attempts while normal user have 5 max attempts. How can I set this value dynamically at runtime?

Comment: I don't think you can. It's a static configuration setting that applies to all users. However you could add a Property FailedAttempts to the ApplicationUser and check it on login.
Or based on a role like manager/user.

Comment: Great suggestion @jeb. I already have the property at the user level, but I wanted to stick to Identity for the lockout management as much as possible. I ended up overriding the AccessFailed method, and using my custom attempts and lockout time instead of the values from Options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up overriding the AccessFailedAsync method, and using my custom attempts and lockout time instead of the values from Options

```
public override async Task<IdentityResult> AccessFailedAsync(ApplicationUser user)
    {
        ThrowIfDisposed();
        var store = GetUserLockoutStore();
        if (user == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(user));
        }
        
         

        // If this puts the user over the threshold for lockout, lock them out and reset the access failed count
        var count = await store.IncrementAccessFailedCountAsync(user, CancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
        if (count < user.MaxAttempts)
        {
            return await UpdateUserAsync(user).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }

        await store.SetLockoutEndDateAsync(user, DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.Add(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(user.BlockTime)),
            CancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
        await store.ResetAccessFailedCountAsync(user, CancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
        return await UpdateUserAsync(user).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
```